# An svd-like tensor decomposition splitting a tensor into two lower-dimensional tensors and a singular vector

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, svd, multilinear-algebra, tensor-decomposition

*I have also posted this question on mathoverflow, but it seems there are a lot of questions related to SVDs here and a tag "tensor-decomposition", so I will give it a shot.*

I am looking for information on a specific type of tensor/matrix decomposition which is quite similar to the SVD for matrices but does not look like the HOSVD since the core tensor is only a vector. Given a rank-$p$ Tensor $A_{i_1,\ldots,i_p}\in\mathbb{F}^{n_1,\ldots,n_p}$ the decomposition I am looking for should be something like

$$ A_{i_1,\ldots,i_p} = \sum_{\alpha} U_{i_1,\ldots,i_q,\alpha}\ \Sigma_{\alpha}\ V^{*}_{\alpha,i_{q+1}\ldots,i_p}$$

for some $1\leq q\leq p$ and where $^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose. Basically, $A$ is factored into two tensors $U$ and $V$ and a "singular value" vector $\Sigma$ with $\Sigma_{\alpha}>0$. Most importantly, note that the dimensions of $A$ are "split" after $i_q$ with $U$ having $q+1$ dimensions and $V^*$ having $i-q+1$. The requirements on $U$ and $V$ should be similar to those from the regular SVD. For example,

$$ \sum_{\alpha} U_{i_1,\ldots,i_q,\alpha} U^{*}_{i_1',\ldots,i_q',\alpha} = \prod_{j}\delta_{i_j,i_j'}$$

but also, more generally

$$ \sum_{i_{\beta}} U_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\beta},\ldots,i_q} U^{*}_{i_1',\ldots,i_{\beta},\ldots,i_q',\alpha} = \prod_{j\neq \beta}\delta_{i_j,i_j'}$$

for all $1\leq \beta \leq q$ and analogous for $V$.

which would correspond to the unitarity of the matrices $U$ and $V$ for the regular SVD.

An interesting special case of such a decomposition would be the symmetric case $U=V$.

Several questions arise from this, such as the existence and uniqueness of such a decomposition. Does it have an established name? Is there more information you can give me on such a decomposition? I am also looking for helpful literature.

## Update

From what I have found, this could be described as PARAFAC with orthogonal rank-$1$ vectors and positive $\lambda_r$. I have found something called WON-PARAFAC ("Weighted orthogonal non-negative PARAFAC") but I still need to do more research.

Comment: It is not "quite similar", it is another version of SVD. It is well explained for example in the fantastic books of G. Strang.

Comment: @JeanMarie Do you have a more detailed reference?

Comment: 'Linear Algebra and Learning from Data' (2019) by Gilbert Strang  ISBN : 978-06921963-8-0 . You can find exceirpts here: http://math.mit.edu/~gs/learningfromdata/ . See as well : https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-065-matrix-methods-in-data-analysis-signal-processing-and-machine-learning-spring-2018/

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. Do you perhaps know where in the book such an SVD is mentioned/described?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have it anymore with me.

Comment: What I fear is that I haven't addressed your about **higher order** extensions of SVD.

Comment: @JeanMarie I could not find anything in the book, but there was a reference leading me to CANDECOM/PARAFAC. This is quite similar, but not fully what I need since, as I udnerstood it, the singular values are not positive real numbers and the vectors are not unitary.